# Why did I lose this poker hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em

The five cards on the board were: 2 J J A 9.

My opponent had A 6 and I had A 5. Do we use the highest five cards or is it high card kicker?

Comment: As Paulpro points out, the suits of the cards would be helpful in figuring out the correct result.

Comment: Without suits, your hand is AAJJ9, and your opponent's hand is exactly the same...you should not have lost. Unless, as some point out, his suited A6 matched the suit of the 2,J, and 9 on the board, or his 6 matched the suit of the 2,J,A,9 on board.

Answer (score 5):

You lost because your opponent had a flush. If he did not have a flush, then you didn't lose.

If neither of you had a flush, you tied, both with the same hand: `AAJJ9`